# How to remove unity and install XFCE4 for 16.04

Tags: unity, xubuntu, xfce

I have installed standard ubuntu in a VM but it's running too slow. I would like to remove unity and install XFCE4 instead. I would also like to keep the extra applications like Libreoffice and so.

What is the best way to do this?

I've found this old [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574481/how-can-i-install-xfce-and-completely-remove-unity) (for 12.04) and also this [site](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative) which show different commands so I don't know what to do.

Comment: The commands given in https://askubuntu.com/questions/574481/how-can-i-install-xfce-and-completely-remove-unity should work fine. The command in the site https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative installs few additional applications ( a text editor and package manager) in addition to installing the xfce desktop environment. However that is optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something similar, but for `gnome-shell`.

If you want to "convert" to a xubuntu, you should do:

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```

Log out, change to the `xfce`-session in lightdm (by clicking on the icon, top icon to the right of your user) and log in.

Remove `ubuntu-desktop` meta package:

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop
```

If you only want to install `xfce` and remove `unity`, but keep the packages provided by `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
sudo apt install xfce4
```

Do the same log out/change session/log in procedure as noted above.

Remove `unity`:

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove unity unity8
```

Comment: with sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop i got unmet dependencies: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xubuntu-desktop : Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: xubuntu-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So I tried sudo apt install xfce4 which is installing at the moment

Comment: I've finished installing XFCE4 but I'm unable to boot to GUI: sudo start lightdm resulted in error (don't remember exactly: something with upstart and permission denied). I then installed xubuntu-desktop which did work this time. 
If i want to remove unity now; which command should I use please?

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't provide the full error message. Use the last command to purge/remove unity packages.

Comment: I think I'll leave it like that with unity installed. It works which is the most important. Sorry that I don't have the full error, forgot to note it down. Thanks for your help, my problem has been solved!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it work?

```
sudo apt-get remove unity
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```