# How to remove XFCE login wallpaper

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, login, xfce

I made the terrible mistake of installing xubuntu-desktop. Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932809/how-to-remove-unity-and-install-xfce4-for-16-04) I was able to purge almost all XFCE related components. However, the bright blue mouse-themed wallpaper is still shown when I login, logout and reboot. How do I get rid of this and revert it to the default wallpaper? I tried [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/64002/13217), but it had no effect.

Comment: It may not be a wallpaer, but instead a plymouth screen (which shows on boot, shutdown & reboot).   Try `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` followed by `sudo update-initramfs -u` (first will show a list of plymouth screens installed; you select one, second command re-creates initial-ramdisk to reflect change)...

Comment: @guiverc That was it, thanks. Consider leaving an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion (*now confirmed*) was that it wasn't a wallpaper, but in fact a plymouth screen. The plymouth screen is the 'splash' graphic screen that hides the boot messages.

Use the commands

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

The first command will show a list of plymouth screens installed; letting you select one. The second command re-creates initial-ramdisk to reflect change which you'll see next time.

Comment: FYI:  if you didn't have the XFCE 'mouse' option; it'd already been deleted when you removed the DEsktop  (*which is a great one in my opinion*); and would possibly have been replaced when the second command was next run, which may have been next kernel upgrade etc...  But this is a guess.

Comment: Did not work for me. Ubuntu 22.04.